# where's the SurfaceFlinger process in systrace resulting html file?

Tags: android, systrace

according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html#overview), there should be a SurfaceFlinger process in the graph so I can use it to find the cause of missing frames. I used to see it, but now a bunch of package names become ..., see below.

[image][image]

So how could I address my performance issues using this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "CPU Scheduler".  Without "sched" it may not get the process / thread names.  (Note this may require root on the device.)

Some of the rows (e.g. VSYNC) are coming from SurfaceFlinger, so the data is there, just not labeled.